# Is there a good way for flutter to layout a large paragraph?

Tags: layout, flutter, paragraph

In flutter, I want to layout a large paragraph to cut them into pages.But when called Paragraph.layout, it cost a long time and blocks UI.

When I make a second call on layout, the layout is faster.

I've tried to use isolate, but error reports that the `Paragraph_Layout`(I found it's a C++ class method) is not found.I guess SkyEngine is not loaded in isolate.

```dart
// line 1563
void _layout(double width) native 'Paragraph_layout'
```

I also tried to layout paragraph in native code (android/objc) and cut into lines,but when draw in flutter, lines are different. I have set bot native and flutter use the same font typeface(monospace).

Any good way to solve this?

Comment: what do you mean by `"large paragraph"`? is it really one huge paragraph (without any line breaks, as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragraph#In_computing))?

Comment: "large paragraph" like a chapter content, with many paragraphs, I want to split this large chapter content into serveral pages.

Comment: so divide your "large paragraph" into single paragraphs and use them with some `ListView.builder` or `PageView.builder` or similar widgets

Comment: But our business requirements leads me to cut them into pages not only paragraphs. We have interactions between flutter gestures and words in these pages, otherwise we use native .  And in native code, cut pages is very fast(objc~=70ms,android~=250ms), but flutter is very bad(at least 1500ms and blocks UI).If the phone performance is not very good, the flutter blocking UI time could be 10s  and even more!It's unacceptable.